# Django dev server no longer reloads on save

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I'm developing a simple Django app and things were going great until suddenly the dev server stopped reloading automatically on file change. Now I have to manually restart the server every time I change some Python file, which is pretty annoying.

I've tried removing my virtual environment and reinstalling Django to no avail so I guess the problem is with the project itself. In `settings.py` I have `DEBUG = True` and also when I start the server it says `Watching for file changes with StatReloader`, which I assume means that it should reload. Can't think of what else it could be. I don't think I even touched any settings files, just views, urls and models.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> check your `TEMPLATES` of 'settings.py`.

If you have defined your `DIRS` something like this:

```
'DIRS': [BASE_DIR , 'templates'],
```

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR , 'templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

So change it to `'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / 'templates']`, if you don't do this it will cause the server to `restart` again and again.

like this:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / 'templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

It may solve your problem.